# Microsoft Flow to update ‘Created By’ column from Email

Tags: email, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a list for Helpdesk items etc. that I created a flow for to look for when an email comes into the IT inbox it creates a share point list item and places relevant data and attachments.

I have one column “Sender Email” that is extracted from the email and inserted in the SharePoint list item.

What I am trying to do is create a Flow to automatically populate the ‘Entered By’ user from the email address or other means if possible.  Right now I am manually assigning the ‘Entered By’ user which is becoming a pain.

Any help greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I am using the "From" item from Outlook Flow in the "Entered By" column.

That is working great now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).